# failure to get the 95%CI of D index using 'survcomp' and 'boot' package

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have used 'survcomp' to calculate the D index of the prediction model. The code was listed as follows:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("survcomp")
library(survcomp)
set.seed(12345)
age <- rnorm(100, 50, 10)
stime <- rexp(100)
cens <- runif(100,.5,2)
sevent <- as.numeric(stime <= cens)
stime <- pmin(stime, cens)
D.index(x=age, surv.time=stime, surv.event=sevent)
```

When I used 'boot' package to calculate 95%CI of D index for the model.

### Calculation of CI of D index

```
library(boot)
df <- data.frame(age, size, stime, sevent, cens)
boot_Dindex <- function(x, surv.time, surv.event, data, indices){
  d <- data[indices,]
  Dindex <- D.index(x=x, surv.time=surv.time, surv.event=surv.event)
  return(Dindex$d.index)
} 
set.seed(1234)
results <- boot(data=df,x=df$age, surv.time=df$stime, surv.event=df$sevent, statistic = boot_Dindex, R= 1000)  
print(results)
```

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
Call:
boot(data = small_intestine_2004, statistic = boot_Dindex, R = 1000, 
    x = nomogram, surv.time = Time, surv.event = CSS)

Bootstrap Statistics :

```
 original  bias    std. error
```

t1* 0.9096271          0              0

I did not know what's the cause of this problem that no bias and std. error could be calculated and resigned as 0.